# iOS - Recreate UIActionSheet / UIAlertController drag to highlight

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller, uiactionsheet

How does the UIActionSheet's hit detection work? When a user selects an option and then moves it's finger to another option, the other option is highlighted as seen in the GIF's below. The detection also knows when a user is scrolling.

[image: First GIF]
[image: Second GIF with scrolling]

Comment: You need a Event for the Action or Cancel Button? Please elaborate more.

Comment: I want to recreate the highlight function in the ActionSheet. When the user selects and holds a UIAlertAction and then drags to the next UIAlertAction, the next one is selected.

Answer (score 3):

So this is achieved by listening for multiple `UIControlEvents`. Chances are you're used to listening for `touchUpInside` as this is standard for `UIButton` behaviour. But there are plenty more besides that. A full list and documentation can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrolevents).

In your case, you want to listen to `touchDragEnter` and `touchDownInside`, making the callback from these invoke some code that changes the background colour of your button.

You should also listen for `touchDragExit` and `touchUpInside` to return the background colour to normal.

Additionally, you should run the action code in `touchUpInside`.

I hope this clears things up!

Comment: I checked the button by printing all the events but it didn't call when I was dragging from outside the button and then entering it with dragging. I noticed that the UIActionSheet doesn't have any UIButtons nor UIControls. This led me to believe `touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)` was being used but this function doesn't execute in the UIScrollView.

Answer (score 1):

`UIAlertController` contains a stack of items in subview with type `UIStackView`, this stack view is placed on the view with type `_UIInterfaceActionRepresentationsSequenceView` that has three gesture recognizers with types:

```
• UIScrollViewDelayedTouchesBeganGestureRecognizer
• UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer
• _UIDragAutoScrollGestureRecognizer
```

You can inspect it with Xcode built-in tool: User Interface Inspector.

I think that custom handlers of these recognisers provide this `drag-and-highlight` function.

Internal logic of `UIAlertController` handle touches and hit test subview in stack and set `highlighted` boolean property to YES for item under user's finger and to NO for others.